# How to solve the inequality from $n-1$ to $n$?

Tags: inequality

I would like to solve the inequality using induction from $n-1$ to $n$:

$\sum_{i=1}^n$ $\frac{1}{i}\leq 7+\sqrt n$

I tried:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}$ $\frac{1}{i}\leq 7+\sqrt{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}$

However, here I struggle to solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the induction step, you want to prove
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} \leq 7 + \sqrt{n}
$$
The induction hypothesis gives you
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} = \frac1{n} + \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}  \leq 7 + \sqrt{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}
$$
and now what we have left is to show that
$$
7 + \sqrt{n-1} + \frac{1}{n} \leq 7 + \sqrt{n}\\
\frac{1}{n} \leq \sqrt{n} - \sqrt {n-1}\\
\frac{1}{n} \leq (\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1})\frac{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n-1}}\\
\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n - 1}}\\
n \geq \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n - 1}
$$
which is true for any natural number $n\geq 4$.

Comment: thx very helpfull!!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to establish the base case.  Here I would compute it for $n$ from $1$ to $9$ and verify the inequality is true.  Then you assume that $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}\leq 7+\sqrt n$ and want to prove it for $n+1$, so you write $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}=\sum_{i=1}^n+\frac 1{n+1}\frac{1}{i}+\frac 1{n+1}\leq 7+\sqrt n+\frac 1{n+1}$.  Now we need to show that $\sqrt n + \frac 1{n+1} \le \sqrt {n+1}$.  If you take the $\sqrt n$ to the other side and multiply by the conjugate divided by itself....

Comment: Why explicitly compute it as far as to $9$?

Comment: May I ask you how solve the inequality from n-1 rather than n+1

Comment: @Arthur:  You can either go from $n-1$ to $n$ or from $n$ to $n+1$.  It doesn't matter.  I went to $9$ because I wanted the square root to be easy to justify the step I indicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} =  \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i}$$ and then use the induction hypothesis. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Hmm, usually yes with equalities. I just dont know how to begin when exposed to inequalities